# Issues regarding setting cache header in firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase-hosting

My current issue is that when a new react build version has been uploaded to hosting yet cache behaviors are really different on each platform. For iOS safari, a new version gets loaded after one refresh, yet on Chrome, it never gets there unless I clear browsing data. To address this, I added the following object to the headers:

```json
{
  "key": "Cache-Control",
  "value": "no-cache"
}
```

the issue now is it is not caching any thing , what should use to be able to only update the current cache if a new build version became available ?

> **target behaviour: keep cache unless there is a new version then update
> the cache..**

My current firebase.json hosting part looks like this :

```json
 "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/cache.mainfest",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "text/cache-mainfest"
          },
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
```